# Text Classification - what can you do vs. what are your capabilities?

Tags: nlp, classification, stanford-nlp, text-classification, azure-language-understanding

Text Classification basically works on the input training sentences. Little or less number of variations of in the sentences do work. But when there is a scenario like

> What can you do <<==>> What are your capabilities

This scenario does not work well with the regular classification or bot building platforms.

Are there any approaches for classification that would help me achieve this ?

Comment: What programming difficulty have you encountered that you need help with?

Comment: It's more of a how to question rather than a programming issue. Do you think I should be putting it on datascience stackexchange ?

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think your question as written fits here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to solve is called Semantic Textual Similarity and is a known and well studied field.

There are many different ways to solve this even if your data is tagged or not.
For example, Google has published the [Universal Sentence Encoder](https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/07/multilingual-universal-sentence-encoder.html) ([code example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/semantic_similarity_with_tf_hub_universal_encoder.ipynb)) which is intended to tell if two sentences are similar like in your case.

Another example would be any solution you can find in [Quora Question Pairs Kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/quora-question-pairs).

There are also datasets for this problem, for example you can look for SemEval STS (STS for Semantic Textual Similarity), or the [PAWS dataset](https://github.com/google-research-datasets/paws)

Comment: Ah ! This is the starting point I'm looking for. Thanks @bluesummers

Comment: Glad to help, I'll appreciate an upvote and a nice green checkmark :)